# Creating table JDBC-MS-ACCESS

Tags: jsp, ms-access, servlets, jdbc

After inserting the values table branch i want to create a new table.The values come from a jsp page.The values are getting inserted successfully but the table is not being created and it does not check the if statement i just have a blank page.
Thankyou.

```
 package Servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


    @WebServlet(name = "Decidetest", urlPatterns = {"/Decidetest"})
    public class Decidetest extends HttpServlet {


        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            Connection con;
            Statement s; 
             String branch=request.getParameter("branch");
             String semester=request.getParameter("semester");
             String course=request.getParameter("course");
             String name=request.getParameter("tname");
             String time=request.getParameter("duration");
             String number=request.getParameter("number");
             String type=request.getParameter("r1");
            try {
                 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
               con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:online_testing");
               s=con.createStatement();
               String sql="insert into tests(branch,sem,course,testname,duration,noofque) values('"+branch+"','"+semester+"','"+course+"','"+name+"','"+time+"','"+number+"')";
               s.executeUpdate(sql);
               String sql3="CREATE TABLE "+name+"(option1 varchar(255)),option2 varchar(255),option3 varchar(255),option4 varchar(255),answer varchar(255)) ";
                s.executeUpdate(sql3);
s.close();
con.close();
               if(type.equals("make"))
               {
                  response.sendRedirect("preparetest.jsp");
               }
                else
               {
                  response.sendRedirect("selectbank.jsp");
               }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Decidetest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Decidetest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {            
                out.close();
            }
        }

        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }


        @Override
        public String getServletInfo() {
            return "Short description";
        }// </editor-fold>
    }
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor. Use a real database.

Comment: Do NOT use Access or JDBC-ODBC. Access is a joke and JDBC-OBDC will be soon removed from Java.

Comment: Ok.Actually this was what we have been taught in college.Next time i will take care. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You should either talk to your professor or change college, he has absolutely no idea about databases. Take a look as HSQLDB or H2, very lightweight. Moreover, you code has memory leaks. You do not close database resources.

Comment: Ohk.I closed statement and connection. Thanks,anything else to take care?

Comment: Still wrong, you have to do that in the finally block. Never use crude JDBC unless you know what you are doing. Use something like Apache Commons DbUtils and a database pool like Tomcat JDBC Pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing two ) after options1 definition

```
String sql3="CREATE TABLE "+name+" (option1 varchar(255),option2 varchar(255),option3 varchar(255),option4 varchar(255),answer varchar(255)) ";
```

Comment: Thanx,Can i use Text as datatype of column while creating table?

Comment: IDK, depends if MS-Access support Text type or Blob equivalent. Maybe [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) can give an hint